# Where is the iOS caret when the keyboard is shown?

Tags: ios, ibaction

I have custom `UIToolbar`'s that sit ontop of my keyboard when it displays and that I use to insert pre-formatted text.  My problem is that I have one `UITextView` and two `UITextField`'s that are potential users of my pre-formatted text.

When the buttons call an `IBAction`, how can I tell which element has focus and is the `firstResponder`?

**Attempt #2 at asking my question smartly:**

I need to call `[textElement selectedRange];` on the `UITextField` or `UITextView` that has focus.  How can I declare `textElement` in a way that it doesn't matter which of the view `UIText*` classes it is?

If I do the following...

```
UIView *textElement = [self my_method_of_getting_first_responder];
NSRange range = [textElement selectedRange];
```

I of course get the

> UIView does not declare selector 'selectedRange'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood question, you want to click some button, and then get the link to you currently active text field? Then you have to go with category on UIView:

```
@implementation UIView (FindFirstResponder)
- (BOOL)findFirstResponder
{
    if (self.isFirstResponder) {
        return YES;     
    }
    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        if ([subView findFirstResponder]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
@end
```

You can call this category method on UIWindow from you view controller. To get window use `UIWindow *window= self.view.window;`

Comment: I have seen that solution posted previously on SO.  I'm a little confused on how this will provide a pointer to the object that is firstResponder.

Comment: If you want to get pointer, instead of `YES`, `YES` and `NO`, you can return `self` and `subview` and `nil`. And of course type of whole method should be changed to `UIView`.

Comment: The issue is not necessarily knowing which `UIView` (or subclass of) has the focus, but more acting on it.  If I have `UITextField` or `UITextView`'s that are possible returns and I want to call something like `selectedRange` on them, how can I declare the proper type?

Comment: Seems that I don't understand task you are trying to accomplish :)

Comment: No worries dig, appreciate it.  I've edited my question to hopefully ask what I'm getting at more clearly.